# Time Machine did not back up because FileVault was encrypting or decrypting a disk. Backups will resume once FileVault finishes

Tags: time-machine, filevault

As of yesterday, Time Machine has stopped making backups because it thinks that FileVault is encrypting or decrypting a disk.  It's not.  In fact, FileVault has never even been switched on!

I've tried...

1. Rebooting
2. Resetting PRAM
3. Resetting SMC
4. Checking fdesetup - it confirms that FileVault is turned off
5. Repairing system and backup disks with Disk Utility

So far no joy with any of the above.  I'm reluctant to turn FileVault on and off again, because I understand it can take days to encrypt and decrypt in the background.  I'm also reluctant to clean install, because this problem is making me question if my backup really is clean.

BTW, I'm running 10.14.4, so I'm fully up to date.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the system messages in the console, and it looked like backupd was having issues accessing some system parameters in an unnamed local file. Anyway, I ran the daily, weekly and monthly maintenance scripts and slept on it, and in the morning everything was magically ok! No idea if running the scripts was the solution, but all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the computer with the external hard drive plugged in to the computer (and not ejected) - that fixed it for me.

**Details on the error**:
I experienced the same issue after installing updates today (running Mac OS Mojave 10.14.4 after the update). The error message shown in the Time Machine window (after clicking on a red/white exclamation point) was: "Time Machine did not back up because FileVault was encrypting or decrypting a disk. Backups will resume once FileVault finishes." This is a false error since I had FileVault turned off for my Macintosh HD disk (verified by going to the "Security & Privacy" page in System Preferences and then to the "FileVault" tab). It seems like this is a general problem associated with the latest update since the same error was also reported within the past week on [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356073/can-t-backup-osx-mojave-because-it-thinks-filevault-is-running).

Comment: Try checking in Console for a backupd error while Time Machine is failing. It should give more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try laying a new OS over the top from Recovery.
It's quick [30 mins] safe [shouldn't break anything, though backup always recommended] & easy.

btw, PRAM & SMC are invariably a waste of time for most issues, no matter how quick & easy; they've become the internet's meme for 'fixing stuff'.
Overlaying a 'dirty' OS this way has more chance of finding & fixing randomness - though it isn't a get-out-of-jail free card either, it's just a simple first step.

Another quick & easy is the 'switch me off then back on again' of removing the current Time Machine Drive in TM prefs, Select Disk..., reboot, re-add.

Comment: Overlaying the OS was a great suggestion. Sadly, it didn’t work. I’m thinking there must be a system constant hidden in a plist file somewhere. Just need to find it. I’ll try your switch on/off suggestion next.

Comment: Nah, that didn’t work either. Thanks for your suggestions though. I’m just hoping that a clean install and a TM restore doesn’t just restore the problem. I wonder if there’s a FileVault process running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I ran:

> sudo periodic daily weekly monthly

from the terminal, as Dave Thompson suggested. Not sure if it fixed anything, but it doesn't hurt to run the maintenance scripts. After that, I ran Disk Utility's First Aid on my backup drive. It said that all the files were okay, but it did resize some "logical volumes" on the drive. After it finished, it remounted the drive, and Time Machine was able to do my backup.